# Conditional distribution of $X$ exponential given $U\leq e^{-X}$, with $U$ uniform on $(0,1)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be exponentially distributed with mean $1$ and $U$ be a $U(0,1)$ random variable independent of $X$. Define
>
> $$I= \begin{cases}1,&U \leq e^{-X}\\ 0,&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>
> Show that the conditional distribution of $X$ given $I=1$ is exponential with mean $\frac12$.

Comment: hint: https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/7/4/1/741c70a333e2b490085840ba22b5e208.png

Comment: Guess: P(I =1) = P(U $\leq e^{-X}$) = P($U - e^{-X} \leq 0$)...double integral?

Comment: @BCLC $P[X \leq x / I =0 ] = P[X \leq x / X \leq -ln U]$

Comment: Anish Darnal, I think you mean I = 1 isntead of I = 0

Comment: No double integral, unless one wants to complicate things. Note instead that $P(U<u)=u$ for every $u$ in $(0,1)$ hence, for every $x>0$, conditioning on $X$, $$P(X>x,I=1)=E(P(U<e^{-X}\mid X):X>x)=E(e^{-X}:X>x)=\int_x^\infty e^{-t}e^{-t}dt\propto e^{-2x}$$ which yields $$P(X>x\mid I=1)=e^{-2x}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Want to find
$$
P(X \leq x \mid U \leq \mathrm e^{-X}) = \frac{P(X \leq x \cap U \leq \mathrm e^{-X})}{P(U \leq \mathrm e^{-X})}.
$$

Note the joint density factors by independence: $f_{X,U}(x,u) = f_X(x)f_U(u) = \lambda \mathrm e^{-\lambda x} \cdot 1 = \mathrm e^{-x}$ with $\lambda = 1$.

Numerator:
$$
P(X \leq x \cap U \leq \mathrm e^{-X}) = \int_0^x \int_0^{\mathrm e^{-s}} \mathrm e^{-s}\, \mathrm dt \mathrm ds = \int_0^x \mathrm e^{-2s} \, \mathrm ds = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - \mathrm e^{-2x}\right).
$$

Denominator:
$$
P(U \leq \mathrm e^{-X}) = \int_0^\infty \int_0^{\mathrm e^{-s}} \mathrm e^{-s}\, \mathrm dt \mathrm ds = \int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{-2s}\, \mathrm ds = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Then we have that
$$
P(X \leq x \mid U \leq \mathrm e^{-X}) = 1 - \mathrm e^{-2x},
$$
which is the exponential cdf with mean $\frac{1}{2}$ as desired.

Comment: The integration in the last part should  be: $e^{-x} ( 1 - e^{-x} )$.

Comment: @AnishDarnal You're right, let me think about this some more...

Comment: @AnishDarnal See if this answer makes sense.  I made a mistake with my limits of integration earlier.  Good eye.